# No se me ejecuta mi archivo CSS

Tags: css, css3

¿Alguien es capaz de ver porque de repente no me lee los archivos de CSS?

Supongo será un absurdo pero lo miro y no veo donde me falla. Hice una base muy sencilla para luego trabajar con php y bases de datos, luego fui a modificar la estética del archivo y veo que no se me modifica nada. Por ejemplo el header antes estaba a un tono de rojo, ahora le cambio el background a verde pero este sigue rojo. Otro ejemplo es que le he puesto una altura y no la lee.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.iconos {
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* ******************* HEADER ******************* */

header {
  height: 500px;
  /*    background-color: #be3144;*/
  background-color: darkseagreen;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

#logo {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: 'Francois One', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<HTML lang="es">

<HEAD>
  <title>VIKINGS</title>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/general.css">

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Francois+One" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</HEAD>

<BODY>

  <!-- ********************************* HEADER ************************************* -->
  <header>
    <i class="material-icons iconos" id="menu-desplegable-icono">menu</i>
    <a href="index.php" id="logo">Vikings</a>

    <a href="entrar.php">Entrar</a>
  </header>

  <!-- **************************** MENU DESPLEGABLE ******************************** -->
  <div id="menu-desplegable">
    <a href="#"> Crear WOD</a>
  </div>

  <!-- ********************************* FOOTER ************************************* -->
  <footer>

  </footer>

  <!-- Llamadas a los JS-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/entrar.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/menuDesplegable.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/crearWod.js"></script>
</BODY>

</HTML>
```

Ahora veo que aquí si que se modifican los cambios, así que imagino que debe ser algo de la ruta ¿no?

Adjunto una imagen donde se ve como lo tengo guardado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: puedes decir que archivo es el que muestras ahí el html.

Comment: Como sugerencia ( no se si pueda ser el problema) pero tu hoja de estilos personalizado (en tu caso, general.css) debe ir al último para garantizar que agarre los estilos declarados en la misma. Comento esto porque veo que insertas primero general.css luego vienen otros links de tipografía. Como buena practica por lo regular primero van los css de plugins y luego siguen los css declarados por el usuario.

Comment: Un buen consejo, pero solo hay una hoja de estilos

Answer (score 1):

## El problema es la cache del navegador

El navegador guarda en cache tu archivo, por lo tanto si actualizas el archivo, el navegador mantendrá el anterior por algún tiempo, hay muchas formas en las que puedas resolver esto pero la que me parece más sencilla debido a que usas php es agregar un parámetro después del archivo, así

### Solución

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<HTML lang="es">

<HEAD>
  <title>VIKINGS</title>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/general.css?<?=date('Y-m-d H:i:s')?>">

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Francois+One" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</HEAD>

<BODY>

  <!-- ********************************* HEADER ************************************* -->
  <header>
    <i class="material-icons iconos" id="menu-desplegable-icono">menu</i>
    <a href="index.php" id="logo">Vikings</a>

    <a href="entrar.php">Entrar</a>
  </header>

  <!-- **************************** MENU DESPLEGABLE ******************************** -->
  <div id="menu-desplegable">
    <a href="#"> Crear WOD</a>
  </div>

  <!-- ********************************* FOOTER ************************************* -->
  <footer>

  </footer>

  <!-- Llamadas a los JS-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/entrar.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/menuDesplegable.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/crearWod.js"></script>
</BODY>

</HTML>
```

### Detalles a tener en cuenta

De esta manera cada que recargues realizara una petición del archivo css, esto puede estar bien en desarrollo pero te causara problemas en un proyecto final, lo que te puedo recomendar en lugar de esto es crear una variable global en tu proyecto php, por ejemplo `$VersionPagina` y cada que publiques el sitio o aplicación cambiarlo y forzar a que se descargue el más reciente con cada cambio, espero que te ayude a resolver el problema.

#### ¿Te funciono?

#### ¿El problema sigue?

#### ¿Cambio algo después de hacer esto?

Fuente 
Bufa. (Enero 10, 2012). ***Prevenir el CACHE de nuestros CSS.*** Abril 4, 2018, de Bufa Sitio web: http://www.bufa.es/prevenir-cache-css/

Comment: No me funcionó el echo :( Pero al menós ya se que es por la caché, que no entendía el motivo antes del post.

Answer (score 0):

Tiene toda la pinta que es un problema de la cache. Si quieres ver los cambios sin que afecte la Cache, puedes navegar en incognito (Control + Mayus + N) en Google Chrome o puedes eliminar la cache.

Más informacion de como limpiar la cache aquí: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ayuda:C%C3%B3mo_limpiar_la_cach%C3%A9

Comment: Si, confirmo que es la caché. Lo que no tengo claro es el motivo jaja

Comment: ¿Has podido solucionarlo? ¿Que navegador utilizas?¿En que sistema operativo?

Comment: No, pasa en todos menos mozilla. Win10